# Updating elements of an external JSON file upon addition of data to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have three files 1)index.html 2)data.json 3)app.js loaded on WAMP server I wanted to add data from my JSON file into a table on the HTML file which I was able to do. The functionality I also need is to update the JSON file as i update the HTML table(using ADD, SAVE and DELETE buttons) and save this table data to the external JSON file.

Here are my code snippets:
1) data.json:

```
{"user":[{"goal":"HTML essential training","type":"Beginner", "date":"20/07/2016"},{"goal":"CSS essential training","type":"Beginner", "date":"30/07/2016"},{"goal":"CSS core concepts","type":"Intermediate", "date":"10/08/2016"},{"goal":"Javascript essential training","type":"Beginner", "date":"20/08/2016"},{"goal":"Object Oriented JS","type":"Advanced", "date":"30/08/2016"}]}
```

2) app.js

```
  var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
         request.open('GET', 'data.json');
         request.onreadystatechange=function(){
          if((request.readyState===4)&&(request.status===200)){
              items=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
              console.log(items);

              for(var key in items){if (items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    for (var i in items[key]) {if (items[key].hasOwnProperty(i)){
                        console.log(items[key][i]);
                        var output="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + items[key][i].goal + "</td><td>" + items[key][i].type +  "</td><td>" + items[key][i].date + "</td></tr>";
                        console.log(output);
                        $("table tbody").append(output);
                        output='';
                    }}
                }}

        }
      }

request.send();  $('.save_button').click( function() {

                var table = $('#goal_table').tableToJSON({ignoreColumns:[0]}); 
                // Convert the table into a javascript object
                console.log(table);
                alert(JSON.stringify(table));


 for(var key in items){if (items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    for (var i in items[key]) {if (items[key].hasOwnProperty(i)){
                        console.log(items[key][i]);
                        delete items[key][i];
                    }}
                }}

 console.log("items after deleting");
 items[key].length=0;
 console.log(items[key]);


 for(var key in table){if (table.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    for (var i in table[key]) {if (table[key].hasOwnProperty(i)){
                        console.log(table[key][i]);
                        items.push(table[key][i]);
                    }}
                }}
});
```

I don't understand how to accomplish this and seem to have encountered a road block. I'm a beginner to JS and JSON and the above code snippets were what i could manage. Please help!

Comment: To update a page on the Server, you need to use a Server Language like PHP.

Comment: Answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223561/read-json-file-update-value-and-save-modification :)